# Characters written so far in snprintf

Tags: c, gcc, c99, format-string

Lately, I noticed a strange case I would like to verify:

By SUS, for `%n` in a format string, the respective `int` will be set to the-amount-of-bytes-written-to-the-output.
Additionally, for `snprintf(dest, 3, "abcd")`, `dest` will point to `"ab\0"`. Why? Because no more than n (n = 3) bytes are to be written to the output (the `dest` buffer).

I deduced that for the code:

```
int written;
char dest[3];
snprintf(dest, 3, "abcde%n", &written);
```

`written` will be set to 2 (null termination excluded from count).
But from a test I made using GCC 4.8.1, `written` was set to 5.
Was I misinterpreting the standard? Is it a bug? Is it undefined behaviour?

Edit:

@wildplasser said:

> ... the behavior of %n in the format string could be undefined or implementation defined ...

And

> ... the implementation has to simulate processing the complete format string (including the %n) ...

@par said:

> `written` is 5 because that's how many characters would be written at the point the `%n` is encountered.  This is correct behavior.  `snprintf` only copies up to `size` characters minus the trailing null ...

And:

> Another way to look at this is that the `%n` wouldn't have even been encountered if it only processed up to 2 characters, so it's conceivable to expect `written` to have an invalid value...

And:

> ... the whole string is processed via `printf()` rules, *then* the max-length is applied ...

Can it be verified be the standard, a standard-draft or some official source?

Comment: Looks like a bug (in the library implementation) to me.

Comment: I expect you should *first* look at the returnvalue from snprintf(). The "side effects" are different; the behavior of `%n` in the format string  could be undefined or implementation defined if the returnvalue  is >= the 2nd argument. In any case, the implementation has to *simulate* processing the *complete* format string (including the `%n` ) to obtain the correct return value, so the side-effect can be obtained on the fly.

Answer (score 7):

`written` is 5 because that's how many characters would be written at the point the `%n` is encountered.  This is correct behavior.  `snprintf` only copies up to `size` characters minus the trailing null (so in your case 3-1 == 2.  You have to separate the string formatting behavior from the only-write-so-many characters.

Another way to look at this is that the `%n` wouldn't have even been encountered if it only processed up to 2 characters, so it's conceivable to expect `written` to have an invalid value.  That's where there would be a bug, if you were expecting something valid in `written` at the point `%n` was encountered (and there wasn't).

So remember, the whole string is processed via `printf()` rules, *then* the max-length is applied.

Comment: Hmmm, the text of the Standard contains **"... number of characters written to the output stream so far ..."**; `'c'`, `'d'`, and `'e'` were not written to the output stream

Comment: @pmg - The characters *were* written to the output stream, insofar as the output stream is a data buffer "behind the scenes" in the printf() function.  *Then* the snprintf behavior of only copying up to size characters from the "output stream" occurs.  See Heinz's answer for a reference to ISOC99.

Comment: then again, maybe the text referring to `"%n"` does not apply to `sprintf()` because this function does not write to output streams.

Comment: Think of how you'd implement `snprintf()`: you'd call `vasprintf()`, then `memcpy()`, then `free()`.  Here you can clearly see the output stream is the buffer allocated by `vasprintf()`, but it happens behind the scenes.

Comment: @par maybe you would do that... implementors who care about stack overflows wouldn't

Comment: How might you overflow the stack, given that vasprintf() allocates its memory on the heap?

Comment: Joking aside, I do realize calling asprintf() would be inefficient and bloated. You'd actually want to write circularly to a small scratch buffer on the stack, but my point is you *still* have to write the whole string.  snprintf() by definition returns the length of the whole string that *would have been written* if the size argument was unlimited.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a bug: ISOC99 says

> The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf
>   [...]
>   output characters beyond the n-1st are discarded rather than being written to the array 
>   [...]

So it just discards trailing output but otherwise behaves the same.